# Can I debug code by running command into PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, debugging, phpstorm

By writing below code I am able to debug my code into PhpStorm.

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('abc:api', ['model' => 'ModelName']);
```

***But when running such command, I'm unable debug code***. Is it possible to debug code by running command into CLI?

```
php artisan abc:api ModelName
```

If yes then please share solution here.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just create Run/Debug Configuration of **PHP Script** type -- it will execute requested command via CLI. The just use Debug button instead of Run. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html